# iOS - SQLite not updating but prepare and step are successfully executing

Tags: objective-c, ios, sql, sqlite

The title is pretty much all the information I have because I cannot find an issue with the code. The same instance of database that is being used in the code below is able to successfully insert, delete and select, but this function does not work. No error code is retured(Always 0), and the program continues to run nominally after executing this function.

Here is the table information:

```
reminder (uniqueID integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, details text, time integer)
```

Code in question:

```
- (void) updateEntryData:(ReminderData *)data
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
    char *updateCommand = "UPDATE reminder SET title = '?', details = '?', time = ?    WHERE uniqueID = ?";

    int e = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, updateCommand, -1, &statement, nil);
    if(e != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with updateEntryWithUniqueID");
        NSLog(@"Error Code: %d, message '%s'", e, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [data.title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [data.details UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT); 
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, [data.time timeIntervalSince1970]);
    sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 4, data.uniqueID);
    NSLog(@"\nID: %d\nTitle: %@\nDetails: %@\nTime: %@", data.uniqueID, data.title, data.details, data.time);

    if(sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Problems updating entry in reminder");
    }

    /* Finished */ 
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I am stumped.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the sql command used works when entered into the sqlite console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes around the parameters. Wrapping the placeholders will make it a value and not a parameter anymore.

```
char *updateCommand = "UPDATE reminder SET title = ?, details = ? .....";
```

Comment: Yup, I knew it was going to be something silly! Thank you. I'll accept your answer when it lets me :)